# Android SQlite data retrieving error

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an Android app.. In which I used `SQLite` database for storing the values and I have two `Button` ->**Save** for Save data and **Saved Data** to Displaying stored data.

When user click on any row of saved data the particular data has to be displayed but my problem is when user press on any row only the last row will be displayed instead of the pressed row.

Please check and help me.

My `Activity` is:

```
public void saveddata(View V)
{
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Data", null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    c.moveToFirst();
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
    tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
    TableRow tableRow;
    TextView textView1, textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5;
    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());         
    textView1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView1.setText("FirstName");
    textView1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView1.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    tableRow.addView(textView1);

    textView2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textView2.setText("LastName");
    textView2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    textView2.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView2.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    tableRow.addView(textView2);

    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    for(Integer j=0; j<count; j++)
    {
        tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        textView3= new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));
        textView3.setClickable(true);

        ett1=textView3.getText().toString();
        //datas11=textView3.getText().toString();

        textView4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView4.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("mname")));
        textView4.setClickable(true);
        ett2=textView4.getText().toString();
        //datas12=textView4.getText().toString();

        textView5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        textView5.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));
        textView5.setClickable(true);
        ett3=textView5.getText().toString();
        //datas13=textView7.getText().toString();

        textView3.setPadding(10, 10, 10,10);
        textView5.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        tableRow.addView(textView3);
        tableRow.addView(textView5);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
        c.moveToNext();

        textView3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this ,SavedDate.class);
                intent.putExtra("ett1",ett1 + "");
                intent.putExtra("ett2",ett2 + "");
                intent.putExtra("ett3",ett3 + "");

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    setContentView(tableLayout);

    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Store one `Id` while saving and pass that `id` to next Activity and then get data using that `Id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey here is your new update code this will help you.

```
 Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from Data", null);
int count = c.getCount();
c.moveToFirst();
 TableLayout table=new TableLayout;
                  table.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

      table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
      table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

                TableRow rowLabels = new TableRow(this);
                rowLabels.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                rowLabels.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.xml.tablerow));

                TextView srnoLabel = new TextView(this);
                srnoLabel.setText("FirstName");
                srnoLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
                srnoLabel.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                srnoLabel.setPadding(40, 5, 0, 5);
                srnoLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                rowLabels.addView(srnoLabel);

                TextView pLabel = new TextView(this);
                pLabel.setText("Middle Name");
                pLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
                pLabel.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                pLabel.setPadding(20, 5, 0, 5);
                pLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                rowLabels.addView(pLabel);

                TextView valLabel = new TextView(this);
                valLabel.setText("Last Name");
                valLabel.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
                valLabel.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                valLabel.setPadding(40, 5, 0, 5);
                valLabel.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                rowLabels.addView(valLabel);
                rowLabels.setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0);


if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                    String f_name = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("fname"));
                    String l_name = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("lname"));
                    String m_name = c.getString(c
                                .getColumnIndex("mname"));      

                    TableRow rowdata = new TableRow(this);
                        rowdata.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        // 1 column
                        TextView f_txt = new TextView(this);

                        f_txt.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                        f_txt.setPadding(50, 3, 10, 3);
                        f_txt.setText(f_name);
                        f_txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                        f_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        f_txt.setClickable(true);
                        rowdata.addView(f_txt);


                    // 2 column
                        final TextView m_txt = new TextView(this);
                        m_txt.setText(m_name);
                        m_txt.setPadding(15, 3, 10, 3);
                        m_txt
                                .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                        m_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        rowdata.addView(m_txt);

                            // 3 column
                        final TextView l_txt = new TextView(this);
                        l_txt.setText(l_name);
                                //Annual_crop_loss.toString());
                        l_txt.setPadding(45, 3, 10, 3);
                        l_txt.setTextSize(
                                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 17);
                        l_txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        rowdata.addView(m_txt);
                        rowdata.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);

                    table.addView(rowLabels);
                        table.addView(rowdata);
                    }

                    } while (c.moveToNext());

                    table.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    setContentView(table);
                }   
finally {
        if (dbase != null)
            // newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            c.close();
            dbase.close();
    }
```

Comment: and also you can add clickListener into every row in loop.  rowdata.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {       }  
           });

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that click event of textview is being override by dynamically created textview. Hence at the end of for loop, last click event will point to the last record. Instead of this dynamically generated table row, you can use custom listview and on click of that you display respective data. Let me know if you want to have an example listview and Sqlite database.

Comment: create method which will fetch data from database and assign data to listview. than you can use `setOnItemClickListener` of listview which will help you to get specific row. Please check this link http://pulse7.net/android/sqlite-database-android/.

Comment: the above example doesn't work ? or you want to modify in ur own code ?